# Problem when triggering the Keyboard brightness with (Fn + F9) and (Fn + F10)

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, drivers, brightness

I'm 05 days trying to decrease and increase the brightness of my keyboard through the Fn + F9 -> Decrease and Fn + F10 -> Increase keys and I can't. I've tried everything but it doesn't work. As I have already adjusted the whole system and I am afraid of giving a problem, I am avoiding moving too much.

My Notebook model is the Samsung series 9 np900x3c. The version of my Elementary OS is the current version on the site right now.

The help answers I found on the site refer to adjusting the brightness of the screen, but that is not my case. I need to correct the keyboard brightness using the Fn - F9 / F10 keys.

When I press them, the animation of increasing and decreasing brightness appears on the screen, but this does not happen in practice. When I press Fn - F2 / F3 to adjust the brightness of the screen, it works normal.

I thank the attention.

Thank you!

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/all/how-to-get-fn-keys-back-after-installing-windows/37dec805-0e63-44f9-8511-141e13271947

Answer (score 0):

Press Fn and Esc once and try to use it. Fn+Esc is a switcher which allows to use functionality. However it may be related to the hardware rather. I have no idea how to remap it, just because I am not a developer. It seems that part of the code responsible for proper working of these buttons is not properly recognizing your keyboard layout. Hard to say anything more about this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll test here and get back to you if I succeeded.

Comment: Hello friend, the solution has not solved.

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/np900x3c-a02us-brightness-function-keys-not-working-w10.806219/

I have found this and it looks like this is the Samsung fault. I am not sure, however it seems there is no firmware nor software which could set properly functional keys binding. Unfortunately I am not an expert. Mostly people are complaining about this in Microsoft environment. So I think in Linux case it will be even worse. Probably you can try solutions from this thread: https://askubuntu.com/questions/172613/samsung-new-series-9-not-all-function-keys-working